# Mass deletion of bad addresses

Tags: addresses, tags, upload

I have several hundred individual records that have bad mailing address and have tagged them in CiviCRM. How can I delete these from the system in bulk? I have tried Civi's upload process by leaving the address blank and using the overwrite duplicate setting, hoping this would blank out their address, but that has no effect.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using Drupal with CiviCRM?

Answer (score 5):

If you completly want to delete the addresses, you could also delete them from the database with a query like `DELETE FROM civicrm_address WHERE location_type_id = xx AND contact_id IN (SELECT entity_id FROM civicrm_entity_tag WHERE entity_table = 'civicrm_contact' AND tag_id = yy)`

Where `xx` stands for the id of the location type you want to delete 
and `yy` is the id of the tag.

Answer (score 3):

See the docs section on profiles and then using batch update from the search results actions dropdown, i.e. search for your tag and then choose batch update via profile, and choose a profile that has your address fields.
https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/profiles/#updating-multiple-records-at-the-same-time

It may have the same thing as import where it interprets blank as "no change". If so, you could try fooling it with a space character as the address.